# Is there a typescript-eslint rule that alerts you when you use a method as a boolean?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

In Javascript, I sometimes accidentally write:

```
if (obj.method) {  // <-- bad
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
if (obj.method()) { // <-- good
  ...
}
```

Given that typescript-eslint is typeaware, is there a rule that detects this usage? I would say that 99/100 times, I am not trying to use the method as a boolean.

Comment: This here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md ? Its not specific to method though, but enforces a strict boolean

Comment: Thanks a lot. That should do it. Looking forward to trying it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on typescript's `strictNullChecks` compiler option (or the catch-all `strict` compiler option), TS will do this specific check for you automatically!

Example:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3kgRgKwC54BveAWxAwAslgAKASiJySQhChXgF8AoXgJYAzeHVx4AdBWq0GJXvEXxe3IA

Otherwise as @x4rf41 mentioned in the comment, you can use a linter to catch it.
There are two typescript-eslint rules which will help you here:

- [`no-unnecessary-condition`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-condition.md) will ensure all your conditions are actually required (i.e. it would catch this case because the function is not nullable).
- [`strict-boolean-expressions`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md) will ensure all your `if` conditions are booleans (i.e. it would catch this case because the function is not a boolean).

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused because I'm running `strict` and am not getting this behavior. I wonder why. I would be skeptical but your example is quite clear in its error: "This condition will always return true since the function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?(2774)" which is _exactly_ what I want. I wouldn't have thought `strictNullChecks` would have enabed this either, given its name, but when I turn that off, this error does go away. I'll have to look into this more. Obviously better to use the compiler than a linter. Thanks a lot.